# "He returned victorious" vs "he returned victoriously"

Tags: grammar

Why would people say "he returned victorious." instead of "he returned victoriously"?

Which one is correct to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one presumes he won the battle/competition/etc. When he returned, that was his status. He may or may not have appeared ecstatic.

The second intimates that he *was* ecstatic, and appeared that way. It doesn't really explain that he actually won.

Comment: I get it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

"He returned victoriously" describes his return as victorious, like how "He returned sadly" decribes his return as being a sad return.
"He returned painfully" shows that his return was painful.

On the other hand, "He returned victorious" says that 
1. He returned.
2. He was victorious.

just like how "He returned happy" can mean that he was happy and he returned, while "He returned happily" can mean that he was happy to return(from like doing some chores or something).

Comment: thank you very much